# XAException occurred. Error code is: XAER_RMFAIL (-7). Exception is: <null>

Tags: oracle, websphere

I'm having this problem and I am hoping someone can help me out. 
I am getting this exception on **IBM Websphere Application Server** instance, and the funny part is that is happening only on one server(from 6).
Why this happened only on one server.

**Error Message:**

```
[5/11/16 10:32:47:975 BST] 0002e067 ConnectionEve W   J2CA0206W: A connection error occurred.  To help determine the problem, enable the Diagnose Connection Usage option on the Connection Factory or Data Source.This is the multithreaded access detection option.
[5/11/16 10:32:47:976 BST] 0002e067 ConnectionEve A   J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource ContentWatchDS_wire. The exception is: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
[5/11/16 10:32:47:977 BST] 0002e067 WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0304E:  XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are:
The XA Error is            : -7
The XA Error message is    : Resource manager is unavailable.
The Oracle Error code is   : 17410
The Oracle Error message is: Internal XA Error
The cause is               : null.
[5/11/16 10:32:47:978 BST] 0002e067 WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: XAER_RMFAIL (-7).  Exception is: <null>
```

**System Details:**

> WAS Version: 7.0.0.21 
>   Oracle Driver Version: 11.2.0.4.0 
> Oracle
>   Database Version: 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: This question is mostly beyond SO. You should clarify, whether you really need to use distributed XA transaction. If yes, then best you can do is to request Oracle or IBM support. Oracle JDBC drivers are tricky when comes to XA. It is not easy to find some bug-less ones. Sometimes it is necessary to download special version directly from Metalink.

Comment: I have the same configuration on 6 servers(the same driver). Why it happened on one server and not the others.

Comment: Hello Joe, the Resource manager being unavailable is an odd exception during normal runtime of the JVM. Most of the time this exception is thrown during the shutdown of the JVM and it's a timing issue. Can you provide the SystemOut.logs from the startup of the JVM until this failure?