# Getting an XAException

Tags: oracle, websphere

I'm having this problem and I am hoping someone can help me out.

**Error message :**

```
[6/24/21 5:20:01:846 GMT-03:00] 000014df WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0304E:  XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: 
The XA Error is            : -7
The XA Error message is    : Resource manager is unavailable.
The Oracle Error code is   : 17410
The Oracle Error message is: Internal XA Error
.
[6/24/21 5:20:01:849 GMT-03:00] 000014df WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: XAER_RMFAIL (-7).  Exception is: <null>
[6/24/21 5:20:01:852 GMT-03:00] 000014df ConnectionEve W   J2CA0206W: A connection error occurred.  To help determine the problem, enable the Diagnose Connection Usage option on the Connection Factory or Data Source. This is the multithreaded access detection option. Alternatively check that the Database or MessageProvider is available.
[6/24/21 5:20:01:853 GMT-03:00] 000014df ConnectionEve A   J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource MegaBroker_DataSource. The exception is: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
[6/24/21 5:20:01:853 GMT-03:00] 000014df RegisteredRes E   WTRN0078E: An attempt by the transaction manager to call start on a transactional resource has resulted in an error. The error code was XAER_RMFAIL. The exception stack trace follows: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1188)
.
.
.
[6/24/21 5:20:01:859 GMT-03:00] 000014df XATransaction E   J2CA0030E: Method enlist caught javax.transaction.SystemException: XAResource start association error:XAER_RMFAIL
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.startRes(RegisteredResources.java:1088)
.
.
.
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
.
.
.
while trying to enlist resources from DataSource MegaBroker_DataSource with the Transaction Manager for the current transaction, and threw a ResourceException.
```

**System Details:**

> WAS Version:  8.5.5.3 
>  Oracle version: 12c

Comment: This doesn't seem to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site; and is also remarkably similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37159784/266304), just 5 years and a few versions later.

Comment: Hello @AlexPoole,
Okay, thank you :)